# Sqlalchemy doesn't seem to manage thread-unsafe monetdb connections very well

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy, monetdb

As far as my understanding of sqlalchemy goes, if you want to execute database queries from parallel threads in python/sqlalchemy you should use the [scoped_session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html) paradigm.

However I have noticed that for the pymonetdb that even using a small number of parallel queries often hang or fail with various errors, e.g. connection already closed, Logical errors on query responses. Ten or more parallel queries will almost always result in the script hanging.

I am comparing the behavior with postgresql/psycopg2 which doesn't show any problems. I have already reported this issue to [sqlalchemy-monetdb](https://github.com/gijzelaerr/sqlalchemy-monetdb) but I am also wondering if I am clearly using scoped_session's in a wrong way. Please take a look at my test script.

```
import concurrent.futures
import sys

from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

"""
Usage: python test.py (m|p) (nr_of_queries)
m := monetdb/pymapi
p := postgresql/psycopg2


make sure you have MonetDB running (I was using v11.29.3 "Mar2018")
and a postgresql server. (I was using  PostgreSQL 9.5.14 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit)

On both servers make sure the database 'devdb' is present and accesible.

make sure you have installed
- pymonetdb==1.0.6
- SQLAlchemy==1.0.11
- sqlalchemy-monetdb==0.9.3
- psycopg2==2.7.5
"""

def _pool_task(sql, Session):

    result = None
    session = Session()
    result = session.execute(sql)
    return result



if sys.argv[1] == "m":
    engine = create_engine('monetdb:///devdb')
elif sys.argv[1] == "p":
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://frank:frankspassword@localhost/devdb')
else:
    raise ValueError("Unknown database {}".format(sys.argv[1]))

# The scoped_session object 'Session' is a factory to generate thread_local sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=engine))

nr_queries = int(sys.argv[2])

queries = ["select sum(value) + {} from generate_series(1, 100) as foo(value);".format(i) for i in range(0, nr_queries)]

results = []

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(queries)) as executor:
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed([executor.submit(_pool_task, query, Session) for query in queries]):
        results.append(future.result())

data = [c.fetchall() for c in results]

print(data)
```